# Symfony 3 Form Unit Test createMock undefined

Tags: phpunit, symfony-3.2

I'm using symfony 3 and PhpUnit 5.6.4. I'm testing my form with  http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/unit_testing.html

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/apizzoleo/c9388a2526385d2fae828ad8c9986225) but when I run phpunit I get:

> Testing Test Suite
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Tests\AnnBundle\Form\Type\AnnTypeTest::createMock() in /media/mpf/mmf/tests/AnnBundle/Form/Type/AnnTypeTest.php on line 26
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /media/mpf/mmf/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-4.8/phpunit:0

Thanks.

Comment: youve likely forgotton to extend the TypeTestCase class, or you have a use statement for the wrong one

Comment: no, i extend TypeTestCase. I think that i must inject same extension that the ttc default not loads.

Comment: I update php versione to PHP 5.6 and PHPUnit version to 5.6.4 now i get:  `Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType::__construct()  must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, none given, called in /media/mpf/mmf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 85 and defined
 /media/mpf/mmf/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/DeprecationErrorHandler.php:73`

Comment: Can you provide your `AnnTypeTest` class?

Comment: You are calling `createMock()` on your form type instead of your test. The error should be easy to spot as the method should basically only be called on `$this`. If it's called on anything else there is a high chance of it being wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My test class is: <br/>  [https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0c4dacdcb71c9969a3d645986519543]

Comment: To avoid any confusion, please edit your question to include the tested class and its test, mention the current PHPUnit version and the error message that your are facing with the provided details. I would also suggest you to read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your class is called Ann*unci*TypeTest and your error message says AnnTypeTest. Is this just a typo or do you accidentally have a file with that name and that is throwing the error instead?

Comment: Also phpunit 4.8 is a bit outdated. Try if there is a more up to date version in your vendor folder with `php vendor/bin/phpunit --version` and if so use that instead by running `php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/`